# Make mpv hold on the last picture instead of closing

Tags: mpv

If I watch a video with mpv, it closes after the video ends. How can I configure it such that it doesn't close, for example just freezes the last image of the movie, so that I can seek back and forth without restarting the video.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You'd use `mpv --keep-open=yes`, which you can find in the [mpv manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mpv/mpv.1.en.html).

It allows three values: `no` (close/advance to next at end of video, the default), `yes` (advance if there is a next video, otherwise pause), and `always` (always pause at end of video, even if there is a next video).

You should also be able to put `keep-open=yes` in your `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` or `~/.mpv/config` (whichever you're using)

Comment: Neat. Can this be changed while the player is running? (I'm looking for a "stop after current song"-option…)

Comment: @Caesar I would guess yes, but haven't tested or checked the manpage. mpv allows a lot of options to be changed at runtime via "properties" which can be set by, e.g., Lua scripting. You can also manipulate the playlist via scripting.

Comment: @derobert debian 10 have this config under .config/ directory, Then put it inside `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` works on it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert) for hinting me towards this:

If you do want to use `keep-open`but don't want that behavior all the time, I wrote a little script to turn it on just once:

```lua
reset_keep_open = false
keep_open_val = nil
function nopause()
    print("Not pausing after current")
    if keep_open_val ~= nil then
        mp.set_property("keep-open", keep_open_val)
    end
    reset_keep_open = false
end
function pause_after_current()
    if reset_keep_open == false then
        keep_open_val = mp.get_property("keep-open")
        reset_keep_open = true
        mp.set_property("keep-open", "always")
        print("Pause after current.")
    else
        nopause()
    end
end
function on_pause_change(name, value)
    if reset_keep_open then
        nopause()
    end
end
mp.observe_property("pause", "bool", on_pause_change)
mp.add_key_binding("P", "pause_after_current", pause_after_current)
```

(Goes into `~/.config/mpv/scripts/pauseaftercurrent.lua`)

However, I could have made my life a lot easier by just putting

```
P cycle keep-open up
```

into my `input.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option which hold the MPV window (not last image) at the end of playback:

```
mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui -- MY.VIDEO.FILE
```